# What kind of chart is suitable for work flow? and it should be free

Tags: jquery-ui, charts, widget, fusioncharts

I have a requirement in my product to create an widget to have workflow kind of process.

If you see attached image , I am looking for similar kind of chart.
As we have already **fusion charts** with us, is it possible to have similar stuff?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have FusionCharts, I would recommend using the Drag Node Chart. The chart is exactly of the type you need and the dragging functionality can be easily turned off!

> http://www.fusioncharts.com/charts/drag-node-charts/

In fact, one of the examples look very close to the image in your question and as far as I can tell, the chart can be customised to look almost same -
http://www.fusioncharts.com/charts/drag-node-charts/

[image]

Only downside that I can think of is that you will have to manually calculate the position of your workflow nodes (the connectors will connect automatically.) However, the positions can be easily computed by writing simple function on the [`beforeDataUpdate` event](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/usage-guide/advanced-charting/theme-manager/creating-new-themes.html) fired by the chart.

PS: Using the [annotations feature](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/usage-guide/annotations/introduction.html), you can dynamically position texts labels, images, and other such items arounds your process diagram.